# Parsing HLS m3u8 Regex

Tags: regex, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I am trying to parse HLS m3u8 file and where am stuck at is matching m3u8 links. So, if `URI=` exists, from `#EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF`, grab the one in quotation marks, and if it doesn't, `#EXT-X-STREAM-INF`, grab the link from new line.

Text:

```
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=263851,CODECS="mp4a.40.2, avc1.4d400d",RESOLUTION=416x234,AUDIO="bipbop_audio",SUBTITLES="subs"
gear1/prog_index.m3u8 <== new line link
#EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF:URI="gear1/iframe_index.m3u8",CODECS="avc1.4d400d",BANDWIDTH=28451
```

[image]

Regex:

```
(?:#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:|#EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF:)(?:BANDWIDTH=(?<BANDWIDTH>\d+),?|CODECS=(?<CODECS>"[^"]*"),?|RESOLUTION=(?<RESOLUTION>\d+x\d+),?|AUDIO=(?<AUDIO>"[^"]*"),?|SUBTITLES=(?<SUBTITLES>"[^"]*"),?|URI=(?<URI>"[^"]*"),?)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lOwJGk/1)

Comment: Please see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/lOwJGk/3), do you want something like this? Match an additional line and capture it into the 2nd `URI` group (with `(?J)` modifier) if `#EXT-X-STREAM-INF` was matched in Group 1.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew You are beyond godlike! Please make a post, so I can up vote and accept it as an answer.

Comment: Are you sure your engine is PCRE? Will it work in the actual current project code?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I don't know. Am using PHP.

Comment: Yes, PHP uses PCRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix for your pattern will look like this:

- Capture the `#EXT-X-STREAM-INF` part into Group 1
- Add `(?J)` modifier to allow named capturing groups with identical names
- Add a [**conditional construct**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) that will capture the whole line after the current pattern if Group 1 matched.

The pattern will look like

```
(?J)(?:(#EXT-X-STREAM-INF)|#EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF):(?:BANDWIDTH=(?<BANDWIDTH>\d+),?|CODECS=(?<CODECS>"[^"]*"),?|RESOLUTION=(?<RESOLUTION>\d+x\d+),?|AUDIO=(?<AUDIO>"[^"]*"),?|SUBTITLES=(?<SUBTITLES>"[^"]*"),?|URI=(?<URI>"[^"]*"),?)*(?<URI>(?:(?!#EXT)\S)+))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9OPleo/3)

So, basically, I added `(?<URI>(?:(?!#EXT)\S)+))` at the end and captured `(#EXT-X-STREAM-INF)` at the start.

The conditional construct matches like this:

- `(?` - start of the conditional construct

  - `(1)` - if Group 1 matched
  - `\R` - a line break
  - `(?<URI>` - start of a named capturing group

    - `(?:(?!#EXT)\S)+)` - any non-whitespace char (`\S`), 1 or more occurrences (`+`), that is not a starting char of a `#EXT` char sequence (the so called ["tempered greedy token"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat))
  - `)` - end of the named capturing group
- `)` - end of the conditional construct

Comment: The only thing I am concern about is if #EXT-X-STREAM-INF and #EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF are in same line.  #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=263851...#EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF:URI="gear1/...

Comment: Changed from '(?(1)\R(?<URI>.*))' to '(?(1)\R(?<URI>[^#EXT\s]+))' and it works like a charm. https://regex101.com/r/9OPleo/2 Again, thank you.

Comment: @S.Kablar Sorry, I was offline. You cannot use a negated character class to  match any text but a sequence of chars. You may use a tempered greedy token, [`(?<URI>(?:(?!#EXT)\S)+))`](https://regex101.com/r/9OPleo/3).